# How to transfer scripts seamlessly between server and a desktop computer?

Tags: linux, python

I have two python scripts:

First one runs in a server and creates a script in lua language.

Second one runs in my desktop computer and is supposed to receive that file, run that lua script and upload the results back to the server.

I have done a bit of research yet not able to figure out what would be the way to do it? Please point me in the right direction. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Include more information, what are your scripts, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for the "ANY suggestion" in the question.

If you don't plan to support large result data, then I would not bother about any handshaking transport solution in your place.
Using redis (http://redis.io/) is pretty easy and lightweight. The server can upload the scripts to the in-memory key-value database, the client can download them and upload the results. You have to pick the right keys for the data to send and some keys for semaphores that show the other side that the data is ready for it to handle... and more or less done.

After some reading security is achievable at different levels.

EDIT: oh, yes, python does have its module(s) for redis.